# Disabled label associated with checkbox using css selector

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I want to disable the label associated with checkbox. The code snippets are below:

**code:**

```
<label for="label1" class="form-checkbox-left"><input type="checkbox" name="labelname" id="label1" value="0" style="min-width: 20px;" disabled>Name 1</label>
```

**css :**

```css
.form-checkbox-left input[type=checkbox]:disabled {
    color:#ccc;
}
```

Somehow it is not working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot use the disabled property on a label element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp. Oh wait nevermind. Didn't have coffee yet.

Comment: Do we have any other option? I guess using css selector we can achieved this?

Comment: @I. R. R.: The `disabled` attribute is set on the input element so that is correct.

Comment: Ok I had some coffee. I think your css selector is not right. Try `.form-checkbox-left  + input[type=checkbox]:disabled`. Note the `+` operator.

Comment: @I. R. R.: That would be sibling notation and doesn't work with nested elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can opt to use the [element+element](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) Selector. You need to place the input before the label, however

```css
input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="labelname" id="label1" value="0" style="min-width: 20px;" disabled>
<label for="label1" class="form-checkbox-left">Name 1</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just double-checked with Firefox, and adding any sort of a style definition to a checkbox doesn't change any aspect of its appearance.
It seems that you are out of luck here and would have to take a different approach by hiding the checkbox itself (not with `display: none;`, but with `visibility: hidden;` instead) and then add auxiliary CSS to actually customize its appearance.

An example on how to do this can be found on http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles
Maybe that helps you derive a method that suits you best.

**EDIT**

If you are attempting to style the parent label of the checkbox, you are out of luck, because parent element selectors are not implemented in CSS so far, although a proposal has been made (see https://shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors for details).

**EDIT 2**

You could try this by moving the label definition behind the checkbox definition:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="labelname" id="label1" value="0" style="min-width: 20px;" disabled><label for="label1" class="form-checkbox-left">Name 1</label>
```

Then your CSS should look like this to facilitate the change:

```
input[type="checkbox"][disabled] + label {
  color: #ccc;
  }
```

This in turn modifies the text of your label.

Comment: If I go with the second approach, then I need to explicitly clicked on the checkbox. As per my current functionality when I clicked on label then it will automatically check the checkbox as well

Comment: Which "second approach" are you referring to?

Comment: Edit 2 mentioned by you works, but what if I have label first then checkbox, in that case is it possible using css selector to disable the checkbox?

Comment: No, because the sibling selector only works when the element to be styled comes second, and when putting the checkbox into the label, that won't work, either (see the `EDIT` section for details).

Answer (score -1):

you can try to do with jquery using
`if ($('label1'.hasAttribute('disabled')){
$('[for="label1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}`

at [for="label1"] you can put the id of lable ("if you want to")

Comment: This is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. It's complete overkill, and last but not least a solution in CSS has been asked for.